# Java Hadoop wierd join behaviour

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

### Aim

I have two csv files trying to make a join between them. One containing movieId, title and the other containing userId, movieId, comment-tag. I want to find out how many comments-tags each movie has, by printing title, comment_count. So my code:

### Driver

```java
public class Driver
{
    public Driver(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.err.println("input path ");
        }

        try {
            Job job = Job.getInstance();
            job.setJobName("movie tag count");

            // set file input/output path
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, TagMapper.class);
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[2]), TextInputFormat.class, MovieMapper.class);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[3]));

            // set jar class name
            job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

            // set mapper and reducer to job
            job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

            // set output key class
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

            System.out.println(job.isSuccessful());
            System.exit(returnValue);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### MovieMapper

```java
public class MovieMapper extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>
{
    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] items = line.split("(?!\\B\"[^\"]*),(?![^\"]*\"\\B)"); //comma not in quotes

        String movieId = items[0].trim();
        if(tryParseInt(movieId))
        {
            context.write(new Text(movieId), new Text(items[1].trim()));
        }
    }

    private boolean tryParseInt(String s)
    {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### TagMapper

```java
public class TagMapper extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>
{
    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] items = line.split("(?!\\B\"[^\"]*),(?![^\"]*\"\\B)");

        String movieId = items[1].trim();
        if(tryParseInt(movieId))
        {
            context.write(new Text(movieId), new Text("_"));
        }
    }

    private boolean tryParseInt(String s)
    {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Reducer

```java
public class Reducer extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int noOfFrequency = 0;
        Text movieTitle = new Text();
        for (Text o : values)
        {
            if(o.toString().trim().equals("_"))
            {
                noOfFrequency++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(o.toString());
                movieTitle = o;
            }
        }
        context.write(movieTitle, new IntWritable(noOfFrequency));
    }
}
```

### The problem

The result I get is something like this:

title, count

_, count

title, count

title, count

_, count

title, count

_, count

How does this _ gets to be the key? I can't understand it. There is an if statment checking if there is an _ count it and don't put it as the title. Is there something wrong with the toString() method and the equals operation fails? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not weird because you iterate through `values` and `o` is a pointer to elements of `values` which is here are `Text`. at some point in time you make `movieTitle` to points to where `o` points `movieTitle = o`. in next iterations `o` points to `"_"` and also `movieTitle` points to `"_"`.

if you change your code like this every thing works fine:

```
int noOfFrequency = 0;                                    
 Text movieTitle = null;                                  
for (Text o : values)                                     
{                                                         
    if(o.toString().trim().equals("_"))                   
    {                                                     
        noOfFrequency++;                                  
    }                                                     
    else                                                  
    {                                                     
        movieTitle = new Text(o.toString());              
    }                                                     
}                                                         
context.write(movieTitle, new IntWritable(noOfFrequency));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was so obvious.. I should have thought of that but I was thinking that something was wrong with how hadoop is handling threading.